# determine function out type based on input Enum c#

Tags: c#, dll, enums, out

I have 3rd party DLL

which have an enum with 70 values

and a function that based on that get that enum and set the return value

but my problem that the this functions 19 overloads on the out value

if there a clean way to do it(not using `if-else`, or create a huge `dictionary`)

here's my sample code (i used 3 out values as an example but there are much more options)

```
public static dynamic getHardwareValue(HardwareValue hardwareValue)
    {
        string strResult;
        byte[] byteArrResult = new byte[256];
        byte byteResult;
        int intResult;
        bool boolResult;           

        if (HardwareValue.Apci1DeviceId == hardwareValue || HardwareValue.Apci2DeviceId == hardwareValue || ..)
        {
            if (NativeMethods.AdiGetHardwareValue(hardwareValue, out strResult))
                return strResult;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else if (HardwareValue.Apci1Eeprom == hardwareValue || HardwareValue.Apci2Eeprom == hardwareValue || ..)
        {
            if(NativeMethods.AdiGetHardwareValue(hardwareValue, byteArrResult))
                return byteArrResult;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else if (HardwareValue.Apci1Variant == hardwareValue || HardwareValue.Apci2Variant == hardwareValue || ..)
        {
            if (NativeMethods.AdiGetHardwareValue(hardwareValue, out byteResult))
                return byteResult;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: How are you intending to consume the return value from this method? This sort of code always makes me suspicious. It's normally better to have a lot of separate strongly-typed methods, even if it *is* more work.

Comment: No you can´t do that. You can´t change the methods return-type (which is a **compile-time** information) at **runtime**. Once `dynamic`, allways `dynamic`. Even if you could: how would you *call* the method?

Comment: The only way I can think of would be using a dictionary, which you've stated you don't want to do. Enums as keys, types as values, and then a generic wrapper method that takes a type as an argument, instantiates a variable of that type and uses it as the `out` parameter. I'm not sure it's any more elegant than just using a `switch` statement tbh.

Comment: @Diado ,a switch is worse in this case because each variant of the function are applied on multiple enums

Comment: @MatthewWatson can you please elborate?

Comment: @styx I mean, what would the code look like that tries to use the return values from from your dynamic method? And by strongly-typed separate methods, I mean write a separate method for each type that can be returned, and call the appropriate method depending on `HardwareValue`.